# GNUStep and Class Methods

Tags: gnustep

In the documentation for GNUstep objective c, it states that "it is not allowed to override an inherited class method." It then goes on to say that you can override the version such as [NSString version] in your sub classes.  Is the version method an exception, or is the first statement false?

Thanks in advance :-)